# How is this answer not a duplicate of an ealier one? Flag declined twice, now flag it the third time

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, duplicate-answers, custom-flags

Among four answers to this question: [Function to calculate R2 (R-squared) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40901445/4891738), how is Maria's not a duplicate of Sandipan's?

I've flagged this twice, and now am going for the third time.

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you down vote the answer and then delete vote it?

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? It uses the same core mechanic, but Sandipans shows how to pack it in a function and how to execute it. It has very little difference, but for me it doesn't look like a copy of the other answer.

Comment: Don't expect that moderators are subject matter experts. They can't and shouldn't moderate posts because someone claims an answer is wrong/duplicate/useless. You're lucky that first flag didn't get declined. Also flagging that you bring this to meta is a kind of pointless flag and should be declined as well. Use your votes to moderate content that is not useful.

Comment: Do people stop and think that maybe it's annoying to flag the same post over and over?

Comment: Declined twice, post on meta with "I'm flagging the same thing for the third time". Smooth.

Answer (score 14):

An answer that, in your estimation, adds nothing relative to other answers is not flag-worthy. That's not what flags are for.

If you feel an answer doesn't add anything relative to other answers, you can downvote it. You can even post a comment on it if you feel the need to ask the poster to remove it. And if others agree, and it gets sufficiently negative, you can vote to delete it.

But moderator flags are not meant to be used for these scenarios. If someone has done a literal copy-and-paste job with their answer, that is mod-flag worthy. If the answer is differently worded but covers the same ground, that's not something that moderators deal with.

Comment: Exactly. And sometimes the same thing written in  a different way can help people who are struggling.

Comment: I agree with all of this; the first paragraph is especially important.

Answer (score 10):

There's been three separate mods handle your flags.

I declined the last flag for two reasons:

It's not identical. It may do the same thing, but sometimes having different ways of doing the same thing can be really helpful to people who are struggling.

The second reason is. Don't keep flagging the same post repeatedly to try and find a moderator who will change their mind and agree with you. Frankly, it's a little irritating.

Apologies for poor grammar on my part:

[image]

Please heed what the decline message says, learn to move on. It's a useful skill.

While I appreciate the heads up, it's not necessary  to raise a mod flag to inform us you're taking it to meta.

Comment: I declined the second of the three flags, and I agree with everything in this answer. Flags should not be used to raise technical points about the technology at issue, and repeated flagging to make the same point is not helpful.

Comment: Mod flag about taking it to meta, meta post about flagging it...talk about inception.

Comment: @AndrasDeak it's the Stack Overflow equivalent of the chicken and the egg.